# GNU Awk - don't modify whitespaces

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am using GNU Awk to replace a single character in a file.  The file is a single line with varying whitespacing between "fields".  After passing through gawk all the extra whitespacing is removed and I end up with single spaces.  This is completely unintended and I need it to ignore these spaces and only change the one character I have targeted.  I have tried several variations, but I cannot seem to get gawk to ignore these extra spaces.

Since I know this will come up, I read from the end of the line for replacement because the whitespacing is arbitrary/inconsistent in the source file.

Command:

```
gawk -i inplace -v new=3 'NF {$(NF-5) = new} 1' ~/scripts/tmp_beta_weather_file
```

Original file example:

```
2020-07-01 18:29:51.00 C M -11.4  28.9  29      9      23  5.5    000 0 0 00020 044013.77074 1 1 1 3 0 0
```

Result after command above:

```
2020-07-01 18:30:51.00 C M -11.8 28.8 29 5 23 5.5 000 0 0 00020 044013.77143 3 1 1 3 0 0
```

Comment: Any time you assign to a field, the line has to be rebuilt by concatenating all the fields with `OFS` between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it might be easier with `sed`

```
sed -E 's/([^ ]+)(( [^ ]+){5})$/3\2/' file
```

test and add `-i` for in-place edit.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit ;-)